# check if post title in a custom post type exists in page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I just created a post type called 'Movies', I just added a couple of movie posts using the name of the movie as title of the post. Like

> Karate Kid as a title of one post.

Now i wanted to check if that custom post type title exists in page post type's content anywhere and replace it with a link. I have tried the following, but in vain.

```
<?php
// createa a custom post type named Keywords
function create_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'movies_ronny',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );

//loop throught to get the title and and check if it exists on page.
function get_post_type_title($content){

if('movie_ronny' == get_post_type()){

            $mv_title = get_the_title(); //get title of movie post type

    }
    $wp_posts = get_the_content('page');// get content of pages.
    $content = str_ireplace($mv_title,'<a href="http://mylink.com">'.$mv_title.'</a>',$wp_posts); //perform a search and replace.
    return $content;

}
add_filter('the_content','get_post_type_title');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong (or at best very confusing).

```
$wp_posts = get_the_content('page'); // get content of pages.
```

Your note says "get content of pages" but what you've really done is [passed a alternate more link text](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).

```
get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser )
```

But that is an unnecessary step as you have the post content passed into the callback as `$content` already.

Additionally, you are only setting `$mv_title` if `('movie_ronny' == get_post_type()){` but you are using it whether it is set or not. That is going to trigger `Notice`s.

This should be more correct:

```
function get_post_type_title($content){
  if('movie_ronny' == get_post_type()){
    $mv_title = get_the_title(); //get title of movie post type
    $content = str_ireplace(
      $mv_title,
      '<a href="http://mylink.com">'.$mv_title.'</a>',
      $content
    ); //perform a search and replace.
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','get_post_type_title');
```